# Failed to launch + No such dirc

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Works locally, host has proper paths (95% sure). The command is editing an SVG file that's is in the folder, then converting the SVG to a PNG and posting it for me. All this is in discord.js v14 using the "convert-svg-to-png" package.

```
            const outputFilePath = await convertFile(filePath, {
                puppeteer: {
                    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
                    ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions'],
                    headless: true,
                    slowMo: 1000,
                },
                width: 1500,
                height: 500
            });
```

Haven't been able to find anything in the troubleshooting docs, tried a couple things but nothing is working! Was working until they updated puppeteer versions on me, was forced to update to the latest version ^21.3.6

[image]

Comment: Was working until they updated puppeteer versions on me, was forced to update to the latest version ^21.3.6

Comment: Feel free to [edit] that into your post. Comments are temporary and can be deleted. Thanks. See also [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). I'm not sure where `convertFile` comes from, but if it's part of the discord.js API, maybe add a tag for that so people who care about that technology can find this.

Comment: the headless option isn't getting picked up somehow, also it should be {headless: "new"} now

Comment: @pguardiario I just spammed the headless thing you recommended and one of them worked. Thank you!